# How to measure Stepper motor current when using EasyDriver A3967?

Tags: stepper-motor

We are using EasyDriver stepper motor driver A3967 for running a stepper motor. We wanted to measure the current consumed by the motor using an oscilloscope. Can you give us some suggestions on how can we do that? I read about measuring the voltage across the sense register but I don't know whether it is the correct way? Where can we add a resistor in the circuit to measure current consumed by the motor?

Comment: Do you have the sense resistor installed?

Comment: @Soumil07: Please don't forget to add links to datasheets when asking questions if you want to attract good answers. We like to help but make it easy for us.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwil85yct_bUAhWLtY8KHas-CL8QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.sparkfun.com%2Fdatasheets%2FRobotics%2FA3967-Datasheet.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEwnc02ttICyn6_xZ3cs563IMwxnQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can measure right across R1 and R2 to get the current in each phase.  Since they are 0.75 you must divide the voltage by 0.75.

With resistances this low, a good practice is to put a scope probe on either side of the sense resistor and use the math function (A-B) to subtract the traces.